# Clustering - how to recommend movie based on selected movie?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

As my question states, I am working with clustering algorithms.
I have been clustering movies from IMDB, I have 15 clusters and each cluster contains a genre combination. Now I am struggling with the part where I recommend a movie, how can I do this? I have tried making fake movie data, by making up features of a movie and then putting that data in the k-means algorithm but of course this doesn't work as it has no data to compare it to.

What I want is that I can select a movie or create some data and then get a top ~20 lists of movies from a cluster that the selected movie is in.

Currently I am just doing it in a very cheap way by just preselecting a cluster for a result.

```
cluster_test = prediction_result[prediction_result['cluster'] == 5].sort_values(by =['averageRating', 'numVotes'], ascending=False) 
cluster_test.head(15)
```

like this which shows the top movies from cluster 5 in this instance

Comment: You may take a look at this blog post: https://blog.jovian.ai/creating-a-movie-recommendation-system-using-python-5ba88a7eb6df

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
# Check out all the movies and their respective IDs
movie_titles = pd.read_csv('C:\\movies.csv')
movie_titles = movie_titles.head(10000)
print(movie_titles.shape)


#Import TfIdfVectorizer from scikit-learn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#Define a TF-IDF Vectorizer Object. Remove all english stop words such as 'the', 'a'
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

#Replace NaN with an empty string
movie_titles['genres'] = movie_titles['genres'].fillna('')

#Construct the required TF-IDF matrix by fitting and transforming the data
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(movie_titles['genres'])

#Output the shape of tfidf_matrix
tfidf_matrix.shape


# Import linear_kernel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

# Compute the cosine similarity matrix
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)


#Construct a reverse map of indices and movie titles
indices = pd.Series(movie_titles.index, index=movie_titles['title']).drop_duplicates()



# Function that takes in movie title as input and outputs most similar movies
def get_recommendations(title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[title]

    # Get the pairwsie similarity scores of all movies with that movie
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]

    # Get the movie indices
    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

    # Return the top 10 most similar movies
    return movie_titles['title'].iloc[movie_indices]


get_recommendations('Toy Story (1995)')
```

Result:

[image]

```
# data:
# https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/
```

In this example we are seeing Cosine Similarity being implemented. You can use KNN to do something very similar. I'm sure there are many ways to solve this kind of problem.